# Helix publishing pipeline uses bin folder as source in docker setup

Tags: docker, container

We are using the Helix Publishing Pipeline (HPP) and defined the settings to exclude the default dlls (Sitecore, Commerce, Newtonsoft etc).
There is a publish project in VS for this and when clicked on publish, it works fine by publishing only the non-excluded dlls.
However, when using the same project to create a docker image, it is taking the files from `/bin/` (the HPP bin) folder, and thereby replacing the default dlls.

How to avoid this for a docker setup.

Comment: Can you please add some details on how your solution image is built? Are you using the custom-images example in the Sitecore Docker-Examples repo?

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo We are generating our own custom Images from the VS Solution using Sitecore XC1 base images, and MSBUILD task in Docker file. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the same msbuild command apart of the Docker build process to validate its expected behavior? Based on your description, it doesn't seem a Docker issue, but probably a misconfiguration on the msbuild command.